# How to pass data from a textbox to a label in the same webform in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I just need to do what the user types into a textbox repeat a label in c # on the same webform

Comment: Are you trying to do this as the user types? Or after some event has taken place (such as a button press?)

Answer (score 0):

Try

get the textbox's text to a string and then set the string to the label

```
 string text=textbox1.Text;
    label1.Text=text;
```

or

```
 label1.Text=textbox1.Text; // in a single line
```

it can be put inside a button click

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         Label1.Text = textBox1.Text;

     }
```

Comment: @mason:i have added explaination

Answer (score 0):

Use the Text property of the label to set the text of the label, based on what is in textBox1 at the point in time when the TextChanged event fires. You should be able to access the controls in the code behind.The general form is

```
  private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         Label1.Text = textBox1.Text;

     }
```

Comment: yea, i have modified!

Comment: You might want to explain when the TextChanged event would fire.